# finding the corresponding variable from object

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I'm learning node.js

I have an object like this-

```
environments=[{
            "name": "test",
            "resourceLimits": {
                "cpu": { "min": 0.1, "max": 10 },
            "target": {"targetName": "del", "env": "dev", "region": "us-east-1"},
            "name": "test2",
            "resourceLimits": {
                "cpu": { "min": 0.1, "max": 10 },
            "target": {"targetName": "bob", "env": "dev", "region": "us-east-1"}],
```

I am trying to find the `name` of environment where `targetName=bob`

If `targetName` existed outside the `target` object , i could have done

```
        let myEnv = _.chain(environments).where({ targetName: "Bob" }).first().value();
//and print myEnv.name
```

However, the following is a synax error

```
    let myEnv = _.chain(environments).where({ target.targetName: "Bob" }).first().value();
```

How do I handle nested object with underscore/`chain`/`where` ? Thanks ! Any other ways are good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lodash libray https://lodash.com/

```
var environments=[
 {
            "name": "test",
            "resourceLimits": {
                "cpu": { 
                    "min": 0.1, "max": 10 
                },
                "target": {
                    "targetName": "del", 
                    "env": "dev", 
                    "region": "us-east-1"
                }
            }
}, {
            "name": "test2",
            "resourceLimits": {
                "cpu": {
                   "min": 0.1, 
                   "max": 10 
                },
                "target": {
                    "targetName": "bob", 
                    "env": "dev", 
                    "region": "us-east-1"
               }
            }
}]

var res = _.find(environments, ['resourceLimits.target.targetName', 'bob']);
console.log(res.name);// "test2"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. If i wan to check here for both 'resourceLimits.target.targetName' and 'resourceLimits.target.env' (lets say i want environment to be dev), how do I modify this? I looked at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#find and this doesn't work `var res = _.find(environments, [{'resourceLimits.target.targetName': 'bob'},{'resourceLimits.target.env': 'dev'} ]);`

Comment: @Illusionist _.find(environments, ['resourceLimits.target.env', 'dev']);

Plese accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let myEnv = _.chain(environments).where({ target.targetName: "Bob" }).first().value()
```

Comment: that is exactly what i tried and is in the question , it runs into an error.

Comment: No , you had one odd ")"  around environments

Comment: That was a typo in copy pasting, but it still has an error